# Code Igniter - Dynamic Menus when user logs in

Tags: php, dynamic, undefined, codeigniter-2

I need some guidance. I'm trying to change a menu item "logged in" where when the user successfully logs in the menu dynamically changes to "user dashboard". I've tried passing values from my auth.php model where in a another controller called home I have this:

/check user logged in or not
$this->Auth_model->isLoggedIn();

I've tried applying this to my 'main' controller and make an if/else statement where it has a variable $menuName that changes value based on it but when I load the page it says undefined $menuName. How do I do this?

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {
 public $menu;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->lang->load('auth');
    $this->load->Model('Auth_model');

    $l = $this->Auth_model->isLoggedIn();
    if((!isset($l))||($l==FALSE)){
        $menu = "logged";
    }
    else{
        $menu = "Log-in";
    }
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form'));
    $dataTitle['title'] ="The University Digest";
    $this->load->view('header', $dataTitle,$menu);
    $this->load->view('body_index');
    $this->load->view('footer');

}}

    class Auth_model extends CI_Model {


public function login($name, $password){
$password = sha1($password);
    $this->db->where('username',$name);
    $this->db->where('password',$password);
    $query = $this->db->get('user_account');
    if($query->num_rows()==1){
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $data = array(
                        'username'=> $row->username,
                        'logged_in'=>TRUE
                    );
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
  }    
}

public function isLoggedIn(){
        header("cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in!==TRUE)
        {
            redirect('/');
            exit;
        }}
```

The error is
[image]

Comment: Please show us the code in your controller that grabs your existing menu, and the function that encapsulates this call. Also, please provide the view and the model...for science. Seriously though, we need code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set a session variable when the user successfully logs in.

Since there is (and should be) only one view containing the menubar in your website/webapplication, by checking the availability of that session variable, you can decide on the quality of the menu link in the page!